# Can a Form I-485 applicant preemptively submit a new Form I-693 to the USCIS to avoid getting an RFE that would delay their Form I-485 approval?

Tags: usa, greencard

When submitting Form I-485 (Application to Register Permanent Residence or Adjust Status), one has  to attach Form I-693 (Report of Medical Examination and Vaccination Record). Form I-693 expires after 2 years. If Form I-485 takes more than 2 years to be approved by the USCIS, Form I-693 expires and the USCIS will issue a Request for Evidence (RFE) asking for a new Form I-693. Can a Form I-485 applicant preemptively submit a new Form I-693 to the USCIS to avoid getting an RFE that would delay their Form I-485 approval, when Form I-485 is approaching its 2-year filing date?

---

Example of such an RFE:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Can*? Of course, there's no law against mailing forms to the USCIS.

*Should*? I'd ask the immigration attorney responsible for your case, but my personal take is to do exactly what you've been asked to do. When they send an RFE - respond to it as appropriate. Otherwise - do nothing and wait for instructions.

There may be several issues with preemptively submitting it:

- Forms change. You may end up sending an old version of the form, but the RFE will ask for a newer version.
- USCIS may extend the validity of the form (as it did during the pandemic), meaning you'll waste time and money for no benefit, and may end up confusing the USCIS officers
- You may end up getting bad results from the surgeon because, you know, STDs happen. By the time RFE comes you may have had that treated.
- Cases get moved around processing centers. You may send it to the wrong place and it will just delay things further.

Trackitt reports [mixed results](https://www.trackitt.com/usa-discussion-forums/i485-eb/2241229859/will-pre-emptive-i-693-submission-without-rfe-lead-to-denial-emma-suggested-not-to-send-as-it-will), seems like there's no major correlation there.